# wp_schedule_event not firing

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to schedule an event inside a theme's `functions.php` but I cannot get it to "fire". I'm using the Cron View plugin and it shows the event scheduled correctly but nothing happened when is time to execute.

This is my code

```
if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'prefix_hourly_event' ) ) {
    wp_schedule_event( time(), 'hourly', 'prefixhourlyevent');       
}
add_action( 'prefixhourlyevent', 'prefix_do_this_hourly' );

function prefix_do_this_hourly() {                
    wp_mail('myemail@gmail.com','Cron is working', 'Cron is working: ','','');
}
```

Comment: It seemns that the problem comes from a server configuration - i found the following error logs  [Tue Nov 05 08:07:04 2013] [error] [client 174.123.61.234] client denied by server configuration: /home/xxxx/public_html/original/wp-cron.php   . Trying to figure a fix for this.

Comment: This actually helped me a lot. By checking my logs I was able to find the problem. Thank you for the help :)

Comment: Whenever i'm using the wp_schedule_event I often use the `trigger_error()` function to view variables and see what's really going on in the background.

Answer (score 7):

You can manually run WordPress cron jobs by going to http://www.example.com/wp-cron.php?doing_cron. This is where you will be able to see any errors that your scripts creates, really useful when debugging wp scheduled tasks.