# PHP: Posting tweets at a specific time

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, twitter, cron

I'm building an application on WordPress wherein I have a single form with two entries:

1) content of the tweet

2) time at which the tweet should be posted on the user's Twitter timeline

Form:

```
<form method = "POST">

<input type = "text" name = "tweet1">
<input type = "datetime-local" name = "date1">
<input type = "submit">

</form>
```

Now, on submitting the form, I want to post the content of the text field to be posted on the user's Twitter timeline at the time specified by the user in the form. `$_SESSION['x']` and `$_SESSION['y']` stores the user's `oauth_token` and `oauth_token_secret` respectively.

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submitted']))
    {   
        function do_this_one()
        {
            $connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, $_SESSION['x'], $_SESSION['y']);
            $response = $connection->post("statuses/update", array('status' => $_POST['tweet1']));
        }
        date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta');
        $myDate = strtotime($_POST['date1']);
        $now = time();
        $ti_one = $myDate - $now;
        echo time() + $ti_one;
        add_action( 'my_new_event','do_this_one' );
        wp_schedule_single_event(time() + $ti_one, 'my_new_event' ); 
?>
```

`$ti_one` variable basically stores the time in seconds between now and the time specified by the user. For example, if the current time is 2:00 PM, then if the time specified by the user in the form is 2:03 PM, then `$ti_one` would be equal to 180 seconds. That's the reason why I'm scheduling the event at `time() + $ti_one` in:

```
wp_schedule_single_event(time() + $ti_one, 'my_new_event' );
```

However, on submitting the form, the tweet is not being posted at the specified time. The above code ie code for the form and the PHP code is inside `callback.php`, which is the page that the users are redirected to after granting permission to the OAuth client.

What seems to be wrong with my code? Am I scheduling the event incorrectly?

Comment: The function's documentation specifies the following : "Note that scheduling an event to occur before 10 minutes after an existing event of the same name will be ignored, unless you pass unique values for $args to each scheduled event. See wp_next_scheduled() for more information." It might be the reason why the tweet is not sent. More infos here https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_schedule_single_event

Comment: @SimonDuflos I don't get it. How can an existing event of the same name be already scheduled when I triggered the event the first time?

Comment: Indeed, it can't. It was just to check. Is the do_this_one() function triggered at the specified time or not ?

Comment: @SimonDuflos The`wp_next_scheduled('my_new_event')` function does return the timestamp of the next scheduled event. However, the `do_this_one()` function never gets triggered. I think this is why the tweet is never posted at the specified time.

Comment: Did you register do_this_one() as an action ? With add_action() ? As in this example ? http://clivern.com/how-to-schedule-events-using-wordpress-cron/

Comment: I have, indeed. Do have a look at the code I've shared in my original post for reference.

Comment: Did you try that ? http://stackoverflow.com/a/21694962/4098335 Maybe there's a problem with your cron configuration ?