# Wordpress CRON Runs on every page load

Tags: php, wordpress, cron

I have checked this similar issue: [WP Cron Job Runs On Every Page Load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39196736/wp-cron-job-runs-on-every-page-load)
But it did not solve my issue.

I have set my CRON on the initialization of the file. And checked if the CRON is not set, then do not set it.

Code reference:

```
if( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'import_process' ) ){
    wp_schedule_event( strtotime('02:00:00'), 'daily', 'import_process' );
}
    
add_action( 'import_process', Import_Class::api_call() );
```

Can anyone help me in this case?

Comment: [Nathan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1310929/nathan-dawson), can you help me in this case
?