# WP-cron job added but not running

Tags: php, wordpress, cron

I've never created a CRON job before and my attempt so far hasn't produced any tangible results!

To test I've used an example of another site and added some code to get it to simply send and email when the job is run, in this case hourly.

this is my code:

add_action('my_hourly_event', 'do_this_hourly');

```
function my_activation() {
    if ( !wp_next_scheduled( 'my_hourly_event' ) ) {
        wp_schedule_event( current_time( 'timestamp' ), 'hourly', 'my_hourly_event');
    }
}
add_action('wp', 'my_activation');

function do_this_hourly() {
    // do something every hour

    $to      = 'jon@mydomain.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: webmaster@mydomain.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@mydomain.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);


    // do something every hour



}
```

now using `<?php  echo '<pre>'; print_r( _get_cron_array() ); echo '</pre>'; ?>` i can see that wordpress does see what ive created

```
[1485859289] => Array
    (
        [my_hourly_event] => Array
            (
                [40cd750bba9870f18aada2478b24840a] => Array
                    (
                        [schedule] => hourly
                        [args] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [interval] => 3600
                    )

            )

    )
```

But I can't work out why the email isn't being sent and what I need to do to fix the problem.

I was hoping someone on here could help solve the issue?

thanks for reading :)

Comment: See here for information about how you can debug what is happening with the event http://stackoverflow.com/q/19787375/851885

Comment: that's great thanks :)

Comment: I've tried the link suggested to manually run the job and everything works ok however it's still not running automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what might be going on is you're calling your function directly in your `wp_next_scheduled` function, when you need to call your hook.

So the scheduler function (for you, it's "my_activation") checks for the hook (for you, it's "wp"), the hook checks for the function (for you, it's "my_hourly_function"), and the function sends the email.

Your email function `do_this_hourly()` isn't called anywhere. So the scheduler is scheduling a cron, but with no function to run when it's triggered.  Try this:

```
function my_activation_scheduler() {
    if ( !wp_next_scheduled( 'my_activation_action' ) ) {
        wp_schedule_event( current_time( 'timestamp' ), 'hourly', 'my_activation_action');
    }
}
add_action('my_activation_action', 'my_hourly_function');

function my_hourly_function() {
    // do something every hour

    $to      = 'jon@mydomain.com';
    $subject = 'the subject';
    $message = 'hello';
    $headers = 'From: webmaster@mydomain.com' . "\r\n" .
       'Reply-To: webmaster@mydomain.com' . "\r\n" .
       'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

    // do something every hour
}
```

This is untested but I believe it should work.  I didn't check your mail code, but everything else looks right in my head :P

EDIT - I didn't see your additional action because it was outside the code block, but my code above should still do the trick.